# Exposing gRPC service through GKE Ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, grpc, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm having some trouble getting GKE Ingress to work with my gRPC service. My set-up is the following:

- Deployment running two containers: gRPC server on port 80 and simple HTTP health checker on port 81. This is following the non-proxied example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-networking-recipes/tree/main/ingress/single-cluster/ingress-custom-grpc-health-check).
- A NodePort service exposing these two ports
- A GKE Ingress with two paths, default goes to port 80 and /health goes to port 81

I can hit `<ingress-ip>/health` in my browser just fine. However when grpcurl on port 80 does not work:

```
% grpcurl -insecure <ingress-ip>:80 list
Failed to dial target host "<ingress-ip>:80": tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
% grpcurl -plaintext <ingress-ip>:80 list
Failed to dial target host "<ingress-ip>:80": context deadline exceeded
```

I can hit the gRPC server through the NodePort external IP directly:

```
% grpcurl -insecure <nodeport-ip>:30080 list
gateway.Gateway
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
```

Any thoughts on why gRPC is not working through the load balancer?

My service:

```
 % kubectl describe service gateway
...
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/app-protocols: {"gateway":"HTTP2"}
                          cloud.google.com/backend-config: {"ports": {"80":"health-checker"}}
                          cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
                          cloud.google.com/neg-status:
                            {"network_endpoint_groups":{"80":"k8s1-53077e00-default-gateway-80-c0e88604","81":"k8s1-53077e00-default-gateway-81-ec72f745"},"zones":["u...
Type:                     NodePort
...
Port:                     health-checker  81/TCP
TargetPort:               health-checker/TCP
NodePort:                 health-checker  32174/TCP
Endpoints:                <ip>:81
Port:                     gateway  80/TCP
TargetPort:               gateway/TCP
NodePort:                 gateway  30080/TCP
Endpoints:                <ip>:80
```

My ingress:

```
% kubectl describe ingress gateway
...
Default backend:  gateway:80 (<ip>:80)
TLS:
  gateway-tls terminates 
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /health   gateway:81 (<ip>)
```

My gRPC server is using TLS (with a self-signed certificate for now).

Comment: One that I can think of is this note from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#direct_health) although this is for custom health check configuration only.

You may check this [link]https://defreng.medium.com/deploying-a-grpc-service-on-gke-with-free-tls-encryption-support-336cb0a0dbdf) for tls grpc deployment under GKE. However, be aware that the link I shared is not a google cloud platform link.